# Magento - Checkout not redirecting to success page

Tags: magento

I'm working on a store deployed using Magento.  It has one module which I wrote, which has event observers for checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after, checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_saved_after, and admin_created_order_after.

When a customer places his/her order, Magento does not redirect to a success page when my module is enabled.  When I disable my module, it redirects just fine.  With or without my module, the order still goes through but it's not very user-friendly if there's no thank you message of some kind.

Anyone have any ideas what the problem is?  There's no entry in any error log (Apache, PHP, Magento, or database).

Using magento 1.6.2.0 on PHP 5.

Comment: Try to configure your Magento in development mode:http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/configuring-magento-for-development-debug-mode/ and look for errors displayed in browser or var/log/*.log files

Comment: I have also noticed this behavior in Magento 1.7, when I added an observer on the _checkout_submit_all_after_ event. I'm fairly certain there is nothing being output to the browser that would mess up the AJAX response, because when I did output anything to the browser the loading GIF would just hang indefinitely. Now that I got rid of output it doesn't hang, but it also doesn't redirect to the success page.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having the same or similar problem, I just solved a very similar issue thanks to TonyTheJet's comment here. I am using onepagecheckout in Magento CE 1.7.02

If you have a stray echo command in your code, which will send raw text to the browser, this will cause a problem on the browser side in onepagecheckout.js . It does not correctly un-encode a subsequent JSON string sent by the server to say that the order was processed successfully. Because of that, the browser fails to send a GET to trigger the onepagecheckout controller successAction().

If you are using a protocol analyser or a tool like Firefox Firebug, the crucial JSON string should look like this. The order_creates=true is what should trigger a browser request for the success page:

{"success":true,"error":false,"order_created":true}